# Does Spring constructor autowiring work with generic collection types

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have created an interface (kotlin) and a bunch of subclasses. I added the `@Component` annotation, so that Spring finds and adds them to the ApplicationContext. Finally, I would like to get them autowired into the constructor of another bean but it doesn't work:

```
interface EventTransformer<T> where T: Event { ..

@Component
class LoginEventTransformer: EventTransformer<Login> {

@Component
class FieldValueListRowMapper(transformers: List<EventTransformer<Event>>) { // autowires empty list
```

If I rewrite my interface and remove the generic type argument, everything works (see below). Is there any way I can get the generic design above to work? I like the strong typing better.

```
interface EventTransformer { ..

@Component
class LoginEventTransformer: EventTransformer { ..

@Component
class FieldValueListRowMapper(transformers: List<EventTransformer>) { // works
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Login extends Event, try this:

```
@Component
class FieldValueListRowMapper(transformers: List<EventTransformer<? extends Event>>)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Got it to work this way. For reference in Kotlin: `@Component
class FieldValueListRowMapper(transformers: List<EventTransformer<out Event>>) {`

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for referencing correct Kotlin syntax, I am not fluent in Kotlin yet :)